# Send value from C++ to javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I have a lot of doubts for how to solve my problem. I need to pass a string value in C++ to a javascript web page every 500 ms.

I created a Windows Form in C++ with a timer configured in 500 ms for send this string. But I don't know how to send this string to a javascript page...

I am learning javascript and C++...

A lot of thanks.

Comment: Where is the Javascript running? Is it a webpage in a browser? Or... something else?

Comment: Polling is Bad.  Doing *anything* "every 500ms" unless you absolutely can't avoid it is very, very, VERY bad.  What you should *REALLY* do is revisit your design so that you ONLY send the string when it actually *CHANGES*.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send directly from a C++ program to a JavaScript page. The JavaScript needs to communicate back to its server - either periodically or using a more real-time means such as a web socket. The server can then send any updates down to the JavaScript page.

In order for your C++ program to communicate with the page, it needs to send updates to the server, which can they relay them down to the page.